# bind tables on datatables when click button

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, datatables

Please help me, i want to bind table on datatables when user click a button, but the coding is not working. My code is looks like below :

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<link href="css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "ajax": 'data.json',
    "paging":   false,
    "searching": false,
    "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
});
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add([
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
    ]).draw();
});
$("#button").click(function(e){
    $(".wrapper").html('<div><div id="addRow">add</div><table id="example" class="row-border hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th align="left">title 1</th><th align="left">title 2</th><th align="left">title 3</th></tr></thead></table></div>');
});
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="button"><input name="tbSubmit" type="button" value="click this button" id="button"></div>
```

My data.json is looks like below :

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "1.1",
            "1.2",
            "1.3"
        ],
        [
            "2.1",
            "2.2",
            "2.3"
        ],
        [
            "3.1",
            "3.2",
            "3.3"
        ]
    ]
}
```

The code will run if this code is not in html click but in class wrapper like below :

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
    $(".wrapper").html('');
});

<div class="wrapper"><div><div id="addRow">add</div><table id="example" class="row-border hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th align="left">title 1</th><th align="left">title 2</th><th align="left">title 3</th></tr></thead></table></div></div>
```

Thank you for any helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind an event to `#addRow` before it exists. Only after you click `#button` does it get added to `.wrapper`.

For the event binding to work, the `#addRow` needs to already be on the DOM. OR... you could bind to an ancestor as the listener, like this:

```
$('.wrapper').on('click', '#addRow', function() { /*etc*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

It solved, i just change the position like this :

```
$(".wrapper").html('<div><div id="addRow">add</div><table id="example" class="row-border hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><thead><tr><th align="left">title 1</th><th align="left">title 2</th><th align="left">title 3</th></tr></thead></table></div>');
        var table = $('#example').dataTable({
            "ajax": 'data.json',
            "paging":   false,
            "searching": false,
            "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
        });
        var t = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
            t.row.add([
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
            ]).draw();
        });
```

Comment: This seems to be accomplishing a slightly different job than the original question, but it still takes my answer into account (the element wasn't in the DOM). One practice you may have overlooked is just hiding HTML elements that you want in the DOM but not visible. On click, you can reveal them instead of injecting them.

Comment: Yes Greg, i am wrong to put the coding before click :) Thank you for your help :)